# Heroku Rails JS pipeline issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I've been trouble shooting this issue for a while and I'm stuck.

I've got a rails 4.1.0 app using Bootstrap 4. Everything is working locally, but when I push to my production heroku server, the js is compiled, but all js is broken on the page.

There are no errors in the server logs, however there are errors in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined
>       at application-21bd05413e87683d1fbc6420906ba3317d416c1d0b78d17c25e793b78e405352.js:5
>   (index):85 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. ((index):85)
>       at l (application-21bd05413e87683d1fbc6420906ba3317d416c1d0b78d17c25e793b78e405352.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (application-21bd05413e87683d1fbc6420906ba3317d416c1d0b78d17c25e793b78e405352.js:2)
>       at Function.ready (application-21bd05413e87683d1fbc6420906ba3317d416c1d0b78d17c25e793b78e405352.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.a (application-21bd05413e87683d1fbc6420906ba3317d416c1d0b78d17c25e793b78e405352.js:1)

installed gems:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'puma'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'bootstrap-glyphicons'
gem 'bootstrap-select-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0' 
gem 'bootstrap4-datetime-picker-rails'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 4.0' 
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do

  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.3.3'

end
group :development, :test do

  gem 'byebug'

end
group :development do

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

application.js:

```
//=require tether
//=require popper
//=require turbolinks
//=require jquery3
//=require jquery_ujs
//=require bootstrap-sprockets
//=require_tree
//=require moment
//=require tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js
//=require bootstrap-select
//=require rails.validations
//=require bootstrap/alert
//=require bootstrap/dropdown
```

Most people with similar problems were able to fix them by changing the order of the libraries in the application.js file, but I've tried virtually every combination moving around the jquery, bootstrap, popper stuff without any success.

I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Try moving `require_tree` to the bottom. You want to load your custom JS _after_ the libraries have loaded.

Comment: moving require_tree to the bottom has no effect.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? I thought that would atleast get rid of the `Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined` error, leaving us with one less problem to solve.

Comment: Yea, I just double checked the commit and redeploy as well. still getting the same 2 console errors :(

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your deploy logs from heroku and make sure that your assets are precompiling. Also, you should use a CDN like s3 to serve up those assets instead of directly from Heroku.
For example, a sample from my last deploy:

`Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       yarn install v1.6.0
       [1/5] Validating package.json...
       [2/5] Resolving packages...
       [3/5] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [4/5] Linking dependencies...
       warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697".
       [5/5] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 19.81s.
       Webpacker is installed  
       Using /tmp/build_c920754b3e4f6f8ef59d547c2751d714/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
       Compiling…
       Compiled all packs in /tmp/build_c920754b3e4f6f8ef59d547c2751d714/public/packs
       Asset precompilation completed (27.00s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean`

You should also be able to use your Web Browser inspector to see where it thinks the JS files should be at.